# How to configurre ClusterIssuer to customize certificate duration and renewal?

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I want to customize the certificate validity duration and renewal throughout the cluster. Iguess doing that with ClusterIssuer is feasible. Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the duration of a self signed certificate by specifying the `duration` field in the `Certificate` CR:

```yaml
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  duration: 24h
  ...
```

You can control how long before the certificate expires it gets renewed using the `renewBefore` field:

```yaml
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  renewBefore: 12h
...
```

Details in [the documentation](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/release-0.8/reference/certificates.html#certificate-duration-and-renewal-window).

Comment: I was looking for an option with ClusterIssuer.

Answer (score 1):

For that same you can configure it using the below two field

```
duration: 2160h # 90d
renewBefore: 360h # 15d
```

Things to take care :

The `renewBefore` and `duration` fields must be specified using Golang’s `time.Time` string format, which does not allow the **d** (**days**).

Example certificate

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: example-com
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: example-com-tls
  duration: 2160h # 90d
  renewBefore: 360h # 15d
  commonName: example.com
  dnsNames:
  - example.com
  - www.example.com
  uriSANs:
  - spiffe://cluster.local/ns/sandbox/sa/example
  issuerRef:
    name: ca-issuer
    # We can reference ClusterIssuers by changing the kind here.
    # The default value is Issuer (i.e. a locally namespaced Issuer)
    kind: Issuer
```

Comment: I was looking for an option with ClusterIssuer.